# I can't use french characters

Tags: c#

I m developing a c# hangman game for a competition.

I generate some words that have french characters and my vs2015 is not supporting them. For example when it generates "mûre" word instead of "û" there is displayed a "?".

I tried to go to Tools->Options->International Settings and there to download French language pack. I runned it and nothing happened. My displayed options there are only "English" and "Same as Microsoft Windows". ( I restarted my pc after installation);

Here is my function that generates the word:

```
private void generateRandomWord_Survival() { 
    Random rand;
    rand = new Random();

    if (!playSurvival) return;

    StreamReader filereader;
    int lineNumber = 0;
    filereader = new StreamReader(@"survival_easy.txt");

    if (survival_level == "easy") {
        filereader = new StreamReader(@"survival_easy.txt");
        lineNumber = File.ReadAllLines(@"survival_easy.txt").Length;
    } else if (survival_level == "medium") {
        filereader = new StreamReader(@"survival_medium.txt");
        lineNumber = File.ReadAllLines(@"survival_medium.txt").Length;
    } else if (survival_level == "hard") {
        filereader = new StreamReader(@"survival_hard.txt");
        lineNumber = File.ReadAllLines(@"survival_medium.txt").Length;
    }
    int line = rand.Next(1, lineNumber);
    string text = String.Empty;

    for (int i = 1; i <= line; i++) {
        text = filereader.ReadLine();
    }
    filereader.Close();
    word = text.ToCharArray();          
    initLabelSetup();
    initLabelSetup();
}
```

Comment: Where exactly does this problem occur? VS2015 does not "generate" words by itself.

Comment: I have a method that generates words randomly from files.

Comment: And how does it display them

Comment: Ah, you read from a file - how is that file created and how do you read it? (I'm looking for encoding used). What if you hardcode a word?

Comment: @Hans Kesting - I don't think file is the problem. For testing purpose i assigned to my word variable "mûre" and it displays it the same. It works perfectly for other english characters.

Comment: @ Matti - It displays them in a label on a windows form

Comment: So your file contains `mûre` but the label in your Winforms program shows `m?re`? Can you show us the relevant code?

Comment: Visual studio is and IDE - it has little to do with the program you wrote. You clearly have some problem with text encoding, but your question is unclear and provides no useful information, that'd let us help you solve your problem.

Comment: Code you've posted is unlikely to be related to the problem (except hint of something strange in form of `word = text.ToCharArray();`). Please debug your code and see where you are loosing characters - if you still have problem - post [MCVE] that demonstrates problem (current code looks plausible, also very non-optimal).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a different encoding when you read the file.

```
File.ReadAllLines(@"survival_easy.txt", Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1"));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Roberto, it worked. I tryed it in many different ways and i gave up and assigned one guy in my team to change every character from every file(+70 files in campaign mode)  which is in French with normal English chars.